# Is there a way to programmatically bind an event to a method in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

While the normal way of event binding is by using attributes in the markup, I'd like to automatically event bind. This would be great when there is a large number of instances the component. In my case I'd like to always call a CascadingParameter component in the OnClick the same way.

Something like this:

```cs
public class PrositThBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        OnClick += OnClick;

        base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    public void OnClick()
    {

    }
}
```

But this does not work. Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Can you clarify the OnClick part? Where is the OnClick delegate declared?

Comment: That's the thing. I want to bind the OnClick event to the method (with the same name) here in the OnInitializedAsync() method.

Comment: But where is the delegate defined? Is it a CascadingParameter? You expect it from ComponentBase? You want to declare it in PrositThBase?

Comment: May I know why would you like to bind on that particular point? I mean isnt it the same point that attribute binding will apply on a component?

Comment: @MayurEkbote I want the same delegate as you would get if you used it on the attribute. like <PrositTh @OnClick="OnClick">. But by code!

Comment: @iamrafael As there might be a whole lot of the event handlers in markup otherwise. I'd like to explore if there is an elegant solution to do it in code instead.

Comment: Ok. You can add delegates programmatically by using RederFragment. But honestly, it's a tedious process; prone to errors. If you specify your exact use case for which you think this is the solution, we can figure out a better way to do it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.rendering.rendertreebuilder.addattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_Rendering_RenderTreeBuilder_AddAttribute_System_Int32_System_String_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_EventCallback_

Comment: I dont know if you can apply the same but I add events in my services using `event` and `Action` keywords. Basically, I declare a public property `public event Action<EventArgs> OnMyEvent;` then i bind using `+=` operator just like on your question. So probably you can declare it too in your compoents. Hope that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your Question right, but I will try to Answer...

You can use the "ParameterAttribute" to set a button-Binding (also other things) at runtime.

I used it like followed:

```
//base class from which all child elements inherit
public class SomeBaseClass : BaseComponent
{
    public virtual void AddToParent(object child)
    {

    }
}

//ParentComponent.razor
<ChildComponent Parent="this" @ref="child" />

@code {

    SomeBaseClass child;

    public override void AddToParent(object child)
    {
        child = (SomeBaseClass)child;
        child.SetSomeButtonClick(EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, DoSomething)); 
    }

    void DoSomething()
    [
        //gets executed
    ]
}

//ChildComponent.razor
@inherits SomeBaseClass

[Parameter]
public EventCallback SomeButtonClickEvent { get; set; }
public void SetSomeButtonClickEvent(EventCallback callback)
{
    SomeButtonClickEvent = callback;
    StateHasChanged();
}

[ParameterAttribute]
public ParentComponent Parent {get;set;}

@code {
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            if (Parent != null)
            {
                Parent.AddToParent(this);
            }
        }
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
}
```

With this Method your Parent-Component can render multiple Child-Elements and bind the events of the Childelements automatically.

I hope it fits your needs.